# How to get string from string-array in strings.xml

Tags: android, android-xml

Is it possible to get string from string-array in xml file?
*I need to a string not string-array :)*

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="link_categories">
    <item>http://google.com</item>
    <item>http://yahoo.com</item>
  </string-array>
```

Brabra.java

```
 WebPageCurrent = getResources().getString(get string from string array);
```

Comment: Why can you not just take the item at the index in the array? `.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.link_cetagories)[0]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get String from `strings.xml` you should have `key` for that `String`.But in the above you have key for String array so you have to get String array from that you have to get required String.

```
CurrentWebpage = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.link_categories)[0];
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write below code :-

```
Context con=getApplicationContext();
String[] your_array = con.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array_string);
```

Now you have string array and you can pick your string from your array .

```
WebPageCurrent = your_array[0];// may be [1],[2]
```